# Check checkbox to vanish in the DOM

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dom-traversal

```js
function checkboxAd() {
  let boxes = document.getElementById("inputPomo").value;
  let numBox = parseInt(boxes, 10);
  let boxAdd = document.createElement("li");
  let ulBox = document.getElementById("listPomo");
  for (let i = 0; i < numBox; i++) {
    let boxAdd = document.createElement("INPUT");
    boxAdd.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    ulBox.appendChild(boxAdd);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="inputTodo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
  <input id="inputPomo" placeholder="How many Pomodoros?" />
  <ul id="listTodo"></ul>
  <ul id="listPomo"></ul>
  <button id="tasker">Save Task</button>
</div>
```

I want a checkbox to vanish, when checked with JavaScript.
Problem is, that the checkbox(es) are generated dynamically with the function `checkboxAd()`:

```
function checkboxAd() {
  let boxes = document.getElementById("inputPomo").value;
  let numBox = parseInt(boxes, 10);
  let boxAdd = document.createElement("li");
  let ulBox = document.getElementById("listPomo");
  for (let i = 0; i < numBox; i++) {
    let boxAdd = document.createElement("INPUT");
    boxAdd.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    ulBox.appendChild(boxAdd);
  }
}
```

The above function is triggered, when a number is entered in an input field with the `ID="inputPomo"`. The number of checkboxes appears related to the number entered.

When a certain task is accomplished I want to check the checkbox, so that the checkbox vanishes.

All examples I find deals with situations where the checkbox is placed in the HTML. But in this case, the checkboxes are generated by JS. *Sorry for misuse of terminology, help welcome.*

The HTML part where the parent of the checkbox appears `id="listPomo"`

```
<div>
      <input id="inputTodo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
      <input id="inputPomo" placeholder="How many Pomodoros?" />
      <ul id="listTodo"></ul>
      <ul id="listPomo"></ul>
      <button id="tasker">Save Task</button>
</div>
```

**I don't know, how I place an eventlistener for an onchange (?) event which is generated by JS. Only the certain checked checkbox should vanish. (So if there are three checkboxes, two should stay…)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to add an event to a generated HTML Element you can use this

```
element.addEventListener("click", () => {

});
```

For your need:

```
function checkboxAd() {
  let boxes = document.getElementById("inputPomo").value;
  let numBox = parseInt(boxes, 10);
  let boxAdd = document.createElement("li");
  let ulBox = document.getElementById("listPomo");
  for (let i = 0; i < numBox; i++) {
    let boxAdd = document.createElement("INPUT");
    boxAdd.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    boxAdd.addEventListener("change", () => {
     // DO what you want here
    });
    ulBox.appendChild(boxAdd);
  }
}
```